# How to access tabbar height from other controller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar

I want to attach a view from a specific controller (MyController) just above the tabbar but my problem is how would I calculate the height of the tabbar from MyController so that I could give y position to my custom view. I am trying to achieve with statusBarFrame but it's not working. If anybody has some idea please help me out.

```
let timerView = UINib(nibName: "WorkoutTimer", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? WorkoutTimer
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last
    if let timerView = timerView {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let statusbarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        let yPosition = screenHeight - ((statusbarHeight) + 50)
        timerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition, width: screenWidth, height: 50)
        window?.addSubview(timerView)
    }
```

Comment: why you are not taken the tabBar y frame.

Comment: but how would I access tabBar from MyController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directly take the y position of tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y and add your timerview frame height

```
 if let timerView = timerView {
         let yPosition = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.y - 80
        timerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yPosition, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50)
        window?.addSubview(timerView)
    }
```

Comment: where would I put the first code? as it's saying Variable used within its own initial value when I am putting within my tababar controller

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh - I updated the code, please check it

Comment: thank you so much @Anbu.Karthik but  the the value should be subtracted as 50 not 80

Comment: @AbhayjeetSingh - choice is urs, if u used the 80 its add some space between tabBar and timerView. if you dont want the space then use ur timerView height(50) directly.